# Segment Characters

Tags: character, ocr, segment

i am facing with the problem of segmenting the characters on complicated background. I have tried split image into 4 channels C,M,Y,K but it segmenting still have poor quality
If anyone can suggest some ideas, if would be really great.
this is my source image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lunmv.jpg)

Comment: This is way too broad. There are so many possible way to do this, all of them with various strengths and weaknesses, and all of them likely very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is Gaussian Blur. After that, enchance the contrast of an image. After that, the image became OCRable with my OCR software (propietary). Though it's not clear if the trick will work for your OCR software.